# Wordpress Cron Job Custom Hook Not Working

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am trying to run a simple cron job using a *custom hook* but it does not run. It get's scheduled (viewing via wp cron plugin) but doesn't run. If I change the hook out to `wp_loaded` for example it runs fine. This is in a themes functions.php file:

```
// Schedule event.
if (!wp_next_scheduled ('my_hourly_event')) {
  wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event', array(), true);
}

add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly', 10); // Works with action being 'wp_loaded'

function do_this_hourly() {
  error_log("test"); // Not working.
  $log = __DIR__ . '/error_log.txt';
  file_put_contents($log, "Response: \n", FILE_APPEND); // Works with making action 'wp_loaded'
}
```

I have a few other websites using similiar code with custom hooks and they work no problem. What am I doing wrong here? Did a wordpress update break cron jobs with custom hooks? I am on wordpress version 5.7.1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with `init` hook.

```
function schedule_my_cron(){
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event', array(), true);
}

if(!wp_next_scheduled('my_hourly_event',$args)){
    add_action('init', 'schedule_my_cron');
}

add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly', 10); // Works with action being 'wp_loaded'

function do_this_hourly() {
    error_log("test"); // Not working.
    $log = __DIR__ . '/error_log.txt';
    file_put_contents($log, "Response: \n", FILE_APPEND); // Works with making action 'wp_loaded'
}
```

Comment: @Radmation Does my answer help?